# Ruby syntax question: Rational(a, b) and Rational.new!(a, b)

Tags: ruby, syntax, constructor, instantiation, parentheses

Today I came across the strange ruby syntax in the [Rational](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Rational.html) class:

```
Rational(a,b)
```

(Notice the absence of the `.new()`portion compared to the normal Ruby syntax).  What does this mean, precisely, compared to the normal `new` syntax?  More importantly, how do I implement something like this in my own code, and why would I implement something like this?  Specifically for the `Rational` class, why is this syntax used instead of the normal instantiation?  And why is the `new` method private in the rational class?  (And how/why would I do this in my own ruby code?)
Thanks in advance for your answers, especially since I've asked so many questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you have to do is declare a global function with the same name as your class.  And that is what rational.rb does:

```
def Rational(a, b = 1)
  if a.kind_of?(Rational) && b == 1
    a
  else
    Rational.reduce(a, b)
  end
end
```

to make the constructor private:

```
private :initialize
```

and similarly for the `new` method:

```
private_class_method :new
```

I suppose `Rational.new` could be kept public and made to do what `Rational()` does, but having a method that turns its arguments into instances is consistent with `Array()`, `String()`, etc.  It's a familiar pattern that's easy to implement and understand.

Answer (score 3):

The method Rational() is actually an instance method defined **outside** of the class Rational. It therefore becomes an instance method of whatever object loads the library 'rational' (normally main:Object) in the same way that 'puts' does, for example.

By convention this method is normally a constructor for the class of the same name.

Comment: this is a very important addition to @Wayne Conrad's answer.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Indeed it is.  I changed "function" to "global function," hoping that makes my answer clearer.