# Why is the new method not needed for creating Rational in ruby

Tags: ruby, keyword, rational-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ruby syntax question: Rational(a, b) and Rational.new!(a, b)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034174/ruby-syntax-question-rationala-b-and-rational-newa-b)

I'm in the process of reading the ruby pickaxe book, and I'm confused about the syntax of creating rational numbers.

```
Rational(3,4) * Rational(1,2)
```

produces

```
=> 3/8
```

Why is the `new` method not needed for `Rational` (I also noticed for example I can create a string without the new method)?

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't see that duplicate. You are correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For one thing, Ruby has no `new` keyword. `new` is a class method that all classes have (they inherit it from `Class`) that creates an object of that class. When you see something like `Rational(3,4)`, `Rational` is really just a private method of `Object` (defined in `Kernel`) that makes creating rational numbers easier. For more on those constructor-methods, see this answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9677125/1008938

Comment: Thanks yes, sorry I meant the new method.

Comment: @JeffStorey: Oh. But the rest of the answer still holds. And take a look at that link.

Answer (score 3):

It's a method that happens to have the same name as the class. It's a common [conversion idiom](http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/05/07/a-ruby-conversion-idiom/) in Ruby.

Comment: Thanks. Good to pick up these common ruby idioms as I'm learning rather than just learning the syntax.